# My dialogflow agent is suddenly not matching an intent for any query

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

Consider two of my intents :

1. Welcome, has output context set to 'search', works just fine.
2. search_anime, has input context set to 'search' and all it's training phrases are different anime titles with them set to @sys.any because I want anything the users says to be caught by this intent.

This was working perfectly until today.

Any input would be caught by it as intended before :
[image: Properly Working]

Now, even one piece which is one of the training phrases of search_anime isn't caught by it.
[image: Not Working]

Another thing that I have noticed is that this problem has occurred across multiple versions of this agent. Version 2 is linked to the action in production which was definitely not changed in anyway. It has the same problem.
My current draft has this problem even though I haven't changed anything in dialogflow from the time when it was working.

How can I solve this issue? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The Diagflow issue has been resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you integrating DF with Google assistant?

Since yesterday Google Assistant is no longer recognizing both Intents and parameters properly. Lots of people are facing that problem.

I already opened a issue and am waiting for a solution.

Update :
Issue has been resolved: issuetracker.google.com/issues/165676621

_DM

Comment: Yes, I am using Google Assistant with dialogflow.

Comment: Issue has been resolved: issuetracker.google.com/issues/165676621